# Why are there 50 close votes for own questions?

Tags: discussion, support, bug, vote-to-close

I've just been to see the close vote options in my own question (as I saw the button), and of course I don't have enough reputations to close other questions. But I saw this:

[image]

But this looks like I have 50 votes to close questions even though I don’t have the privileges to do it. Is this for me to close 50 of my own questions or a bug?

Comment: you can vote to close on your own questions. I don't remember when that privilege is unlocked though. It just follows the same vote cycle as everything else. It's not a bug, technically.

Comment: @Zoe I would want to vote down 50 my own questions, "per day"  ????

Comment: No. The privilege just unlocks voting on your own questions. It's not a separate system, hence why you have 50 votes.

Comment: It is very, very unlikely anyone hits it. But why would you want a lower limit?

Comment: @yivi i thought that 50 didn't make sense, thats why :0

Comment: @Zoe [unlocked at 250](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/view-close-votes)

Comment: @gnat thats to view

Comment: its here https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: You're can vote to reopen too. That is something you might well want to do on your own questions.

Comment: @RobertLongson but isint 50 a lot for myself?

Comment: Gnat is right it's not to view *This privilege allows you to view and **cast** close and reopen votes on your own questions.*

Comment: It certainly works better as a limit when you can vote on all questions.

Comment: @Zoe Nothing's a bug until someone learns how to misuse it.

Comment: @JoshuaVarghese "a lot" is always relative... At some point there were no limit to delete own questions... Till people start "rage quit" deleting all posts they made... Now there is limit of 5 (maybe even with moderator notification about such activity)... I think asking  about 10 poorly received question is a lot (so far I asked 3 total in 9 years) but there is pretty much a daily posts "I no longer can ask questions"...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov that is a perfect answer, mind adding itor editing laurel's answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you become able to cast close votes on other questions, you won’t get any more close votes. (The maximum is 50.) It would be highly suspicious to even come close to 50 if you’re only closing your own questions.

This may be weird, but I doubt that anyone has ever abused this privilege to mass close their own questions (rage quitting?). If there was a spate of abuse it would be worthwhile to change the system.

Just ignore those extra votes for now.